# Adding an imageView to a MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm creating an mapView which contain an contain various of different pins. Therefor i've created a standard pin image, which is suppose to contain a imageView, which dynamically will be based on a image in an array, so these should be added dynamically.

I've created a subclass of the MKAnnotationView and then added a imageView to it however i can't seem to access this imageView in the `viewForAnnotation`? it seems like the pinView still is a `MKAnnotationView` instead of the `FBSingleClusterView`?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let singleAnnotation = annotation as! FBAnnotation
    var reuseId = "Pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    pinView = FBSingleClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId) as FBSingleClusterView
    pinView!.image = UIImage(named: singleAnnotation.imageString)

    return pinView

}
```